# When an eigen vector is zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question :** 
Mike opens a bank account with an initial balance of 2000 dollars. Let *b(t)* be the balance in the account at time t. Thus *b(0)=2000*. The bank is paying interest at a continuous rate of 3% per year. Mike makes deposits into the account at a continuous rate of *s(t)* dollars per year. Suppose that *s(0)=1000* and that *s(t)* is increasing at a continuous rate of 2% per year (Mike can save more as his income goes up over time).

**Linear system:**

$\frac{db}{dt}$ = 0.03 b + s

$\frac{ds}{dt}$ = 0.02 s

**My solution:**

$$\det(A-\lambda I)=0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0.03-\lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0.02-\lambda \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\lambda_1=0.03,   \lambda_2=0.02$$

for

$$\lambda_2 = 0.02$$
I get $$s(t) = 1000e^{0.02t}$$
for 
$$\lambda_1=0.03$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -0.01 \end{bmatrix}$$

This gives $$0 k_1 + k_2 = 0$$
which gives a zero vector.

However, zero vector is not allowed. How can I find value of *b(t)* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system you derived does not force the vector to be the zero vector: it only forces the second component to be zero. The first component can be anything to satisfy the system, and anything nonzero to be an eigenvector. For convenience you can choose the first component to be $1$.

Incidentally, because the system is triangular, you don't need to use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to solve it. You've already correctly found $s$, and you can plug that into the first equation to get

$$\frac{db}{dt} = 0.03b + 1000e^{0.02t},b(0)=2000$$

which is a first order linear inhomogeneous ODE with constant coefficients. So you can solve it for instance with an integrating factor.

Comment: Oh yes Thank you... I didnt see that I could have solved it by using integrating factor. Got the answer!